# Left-derived functors

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, derived-functors

Let $F:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ be a covariant right-exact functor between two abelian categories.

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ has enough projectives. Then we define the *left derived functors* of $F$ by
$$
L_iF(A)=H_i(F(P_\bullet))
$$
where $A$ is any object in $\mathcal{A}$ and $P_\bullet$ is a projective resolution for $A$ (it can be shown that $L_iF(A)$ is independent of the choice of projective resolution.

Since $F$ is right-exact, the sequence
$$
F(P_1)\to F(P_0)\to F(A)\to 0
$$
is exact. Doesn't this mean that $L_0F(A)=H_0(F(P_\bullet)))=0$, since the homology of an exact complex is zero? However everywhere I look says that $L_0F(A)\cong F(A)$.

Comment: One usually "chops off" the $A$ and takes the homology of $\cdots \to F(P_1) \to F(P_0) \to 0$, right? I thought that $L_0F(A) = F(A)$ was more or less an axiom.

Comment: Apparently not -- see Weibel Introduction to Homological Algebra p43.

Comment: Hm, that's the book I learned from! Let me look...

Comment: I think that Weibel and I agree, although he's not being super clear on this point. You're taking $H_i(F(P))$; the augmented complex with $P_0 \to A \to 0$ on the end is another thing. He writes that right exact sequence just to show that $H_0(F(P)) = F(P_0)/\operatorname{im}(F(P_1) \to F(P_0)) \approx F(A)$.

Comment: Sorry, how did you get that last isomorphism?

Comment: Just from the last displayed exact sequence that you wrote down: $F(P_0)$ surjects onto $F(A)$ and that's the kernel.

Comment: Ah right, because the sequence is exact, $\mathrm{im}(F(P_1)\to F(P_0))=\mathrm{ker}(F(P_0)\to F(A))$.

Comment: @DylanMoreland Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 8):

I think this is easier to understand if you rephrase your definition of a projective resolution.

Let $A_{\bullet}$ be a chain complex.  Then, a *projective resolution* of $A_{\bullet}$ is a quasiisomorphism (that is, a morphism of chain complices that induces an isomorphism on homology)
$$
\newcommand{\arr}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\ard}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{lllllll}
\cdots & \arr{} & P_2 & \arr{} & P_1 & \arr{} & P_0 \\
       &        & \ard{} &      & \ard{} &    & \ard{} \\
\cdots & \arr{} & A_2 & \arr{} & A_1 & \arr{} & A_0
\end{array}
$$
with each $P_m$ projective.  (Taking $A_1=A_2=\cdots =0$ gives you something equivalent to the 'classical' definition.)  The idea is that these two chain complices are isomorphic in the derived category (the localization of the category of chain complices at the quasiisomorphisms), and so to compute the derived functor applied to $A_{\bullet}$, we can apply it to $P_{\bullet}$ instead.  It turns out that $F(P)_{\bullet}$ is quasiisomorphic to $LF(A)_{\bullet}$ (whereas $F(A)_{\bullet}$ is *not* in general), and so if all your interested in is the homology of the (total) left derived functor $LF(A)_{\bullet}$, $F(P)_{\bullet}$ will work just fine.  Anyways, back to the original question.

In the case your interested in, applying $F$ to the above diagram yields
$$
\begin{array}{lllllll}
\cdots & \arr{} & F(P_2) & \arr{} & F(P_1) & \arr{} & F(P_0) \\
       &        & \ard{} &      & \ard{} &    & \ard{} \\
\cdots & \arr{} & 0 & \arr{} & 0 & \arr{} & F(A_0)
\end{array}
$$
The classical left derived functors are the homology of the *top* chain complex.  Drawing things this way makes it obvious where the indexing should start (certainly not at $F(A_0)$).  It also makes it conceptually clearer why one would perform such a construction.

Taking homology of this diagram gives in particular a map $LF_0(A):=H_0(F(P))\rightarrow F(A_0)$.  It then turns out that this defines a natural transformation $LF_0\rightarrow F$ which is a natural isomorphism iff $F$ is right-exact.  In particular, that $F(P_0)\rightarrow A_0\rightarrow 0$ is exact if $F$ is right-exact isn't really relevant.